# Slow site initial load time

Tags: php

for some reason my website `www.gcprive.com` takes a very long time to respond initially but then loads all of a sudden. Any ideas why this happens?

I am trying to optimize speed in general but this is a profound observation.

thanks
Andy

Comment: You've got [~18 seconds of backend processing](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/121203_8C_BMH/1/details/) before anything happens. That is not normal for WordPress. Either you have a very badly written theme or one or more very badly written plugins, or your server is severely overloaded. The latter is not an appropriate topic for this forum, as it really isn't WordPress specific.

For the former, it is hard to guess at what is causing that kind of lag. You can try disabling your plugins one by one and try to narrow things down. Try switching themes and see what happens.

Comment: Or maybe your CDN is misconfigured.

Comment: do i need to increase the memory limit in wordpress config file? would this help?

Comment: this is the reply from my hosting provider.. i have no idea where these ip addresses come from - they gave me a big list and this is just part of it.. 
Load average on the machine is OK.  Traffic might be a little high. Why do you have so many connections established from the server itself?

:/homepages/16/d201909713/htdocs/logs# netstat -tunap | grep EST
tcp        0      0 82.165.134.81:80        208.115.111.68:52809    ESTABLISHED 14237/apache2-ssl
tcp        0      0 82.165.134.81:80        50.16.111.201:43540     ESTABLISHED 14185/apache2-ssl

Comment: there is about 50 ip addresses coming from Amazon as 50.16.111.201 resolves to..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1.- Review all your plugins. Try deactivating and activating plugins until you find the one (or ones) which are slowing down the loading time.

2.- Install and configure a properly cache plugin. [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) works pretty fine, with multiple caching types as page cache, minify cache (also minifying HTML, CSS and JS so nicely), browser cache and database cache.

Hope it helps... GL!